# Skip an RSpec test case at runtime

Tags: testing, rspec, rspec2, functional-testing

I'm running RSpec tests against a website product that exists in several different markets. Each market has subtly different combinations of features, etc. I would like to be able to write tests such that they skip themselves at runtime depending on which market/environment they are being run against. The tests should not fail when run in a different market, nor should they pass -- they're simply not applicable.

Unfortunately, there does not seem to be an easy way to mark a test as skipped. How would I go about doing this without trying to inject "pending" blocks (which aren't accurate anyway?)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [exclusion filters](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-5/dir/filtering/exclusion-filters).

```
describe "market a", :market => 'a' do
   ...
end
describe "market b", :market => 'b' do
   ...
end
describe "market c", :market => 'c' do
   ...
end

RSpec.configure do |c|
  # Set these up programmatically; 
  # I'm not sure how you're defining which market is 'active'
  c.filter_run_excluding :market => 'a'
  c.filter_run_excluding :market => 'b'
  # Now only tests with ":market => 'c'" will run.
end
```

Or better still, use [implicit filters](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-5/dir/filtering/implicit-filters).

```
describe "market a", :if => CurrentMarket.a? do # or whatever
   ...
end
```

Comment: Implicit filters seem like the way to go. I'm surprised that there seems to be no way for the test to report to the formatter that it was excluded :/

Answer (score 6):

I spotted this question looking for a way to really **skip** examples that I know are going to fail now, but I want to "unskip" them once the situation's changed. So for rspec 3.8 I found one could use `skip` inside an example just like this:

```
it 'is going to fail under several circumstances' do
  skip("Here's the reason") if conditions_met?
  expect(something)
end
```

Actually, in most situations (maybe not as complicated as in this question) I would rather use `pending` instead of `skip`, 'cause it will notify me if tests stop failing, so I can "unskip" them. As we all know that skipped tests will never be performed ever again =)

Comment: @andrewdotnich Actually I would rather use `pending` instead of `skip`, 'cause it will notify me if tests stop failing, so I can "unskip" them. As we all know that skipped tests will never be performed ever again =) Will edit my reply in a sec